Disable nested jar scanning for kotest plugin
In one of my module B i have a dependency to another module A (test helpers):
        <dependency>
            <groupId>my.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>another-module</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

When i'm trying to run all tests from module B by using kotest plugin inside Intellij, it has also executed every test from A

Problem happens only for intellij/plugin, running tests with a maven works fine, no tests from A are executed.
I've tried exclude most of the files from test-jar, but looks like plugin takes into consideration the source code itself.
Is there a way to exclude nested jar test classes from execution?

Better post the ask here: https://github.com/kotest/kotest/issues

@BondHan that was my first ideah, however i can't create new issues on their github, probably due to some policies or idk. Btw they marked stackoverflow as one of communication channel
